# Continuously pass Values in Tkinter and ammend it accordingly

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

The purpose is that input fn takes string input and pass it into GUI fn which runs the condition and ammend tkinter window accordingly.

```
#*********************************** IMPORTING MODULES*****************
import tkinter
from tkinter import*
import tkinter.messagebox
import sqlite3
import os
import threading
from time import sleep
from input import*
conn = sqlite3.connect('portal.db')
c = conn.cursor()
global a
#*************** TKINTER GUI CODE******************
def gui(a):
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("Smart Notice Board")

    #********************** FRAMES OF MAIN WINDOW(HOME)******************

    top = Canvas(window,width=1024,height=184)
    top.pack(fill=X)

    middle = Canvas(window, width=1024, height=450, bg='steelblue')
    middle.pack(fill=X)

    main_left = Canvas(middle, width=275, height=450, bg='lightgreen')
    main_left.pack(side=LEFT)

    main_right = Canvas(middle, width=800, height=450, bg='steelblue')
    main_right.pack(side=RIGHT)

    bottom = Canvas(window, width=1024, height=70, bg='black')
    bottom.pack(fill=X)
    #************************** IMAGES********************

    i_top = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='F:\\C_backup\\fyp\\5 jan 2k19\\BG.png')
    top.create_image(0,10, anchor=tkinter.NW,image = i_top)
    i_right = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='F:\\C_backup\\fyp\\5 jan 2k19\\aus1.png')
    main_right.create_image(0,0, anchor=tkinter.NW,image = i_right)
    #i_left = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='F:\\C_backup\\fyp\\5 jan 2k19\\widget1.png')
    #main_left.create_image(0,0, anchor=tkinter.NW,image = i_left)


    t1 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='F:\\C_backup\\fyp\\5 jan 2k19\\first.png')
    t2 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='F:\\C_backup\\fyp\\5 jan 2k19\\BG.png')


    #***************** TIMETABLE IMAGE VIEWING FN***********************

    def home():

        main_right.create_image(0,0, anchor=tkinter.NW,image = t2)

    #*********************** TIMETABLE BUTTON PRESS FN*************************
    def timetable():

        main_right.create_image(0,0, anchor=tkinter.NW,image = t1)


    #******************************* CONDITIONS**********************
    if a == "NULL":
        timetable()
    if a == "HOME":
        home()
    #*********************** MAIN MENU BUTTONS****************

    button_1 = Button(text = '  HOME', anchor = 'w', height = 2, width = 8,activebackground = '#33B5e5',bg = 'brown',fg = 'white',command = home)
    top.create_window(2,150,anchor = 'nw', window = button_1)


    button_2 = Button(text='TIMETABLE', height = 2, width=12, activebackground = '#33B5e5', bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',command = timetable)
    top.create_window(75,150, anchor='nw', window = button_2)
    window.mainloop()


#************************** MAIN LOOP************************

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #print(valuea())
    a=valuea()
    gui(a)
```

Now what I want is continuously run that thing and update Tkinter window; but the 2btn fn only takes it one time and pass it into GUI fn which runs tkinter and it stucks on window.mainloop as tkinter is infinity loop.
Please suggest me a solution also u can run this code by only setting pictures from your computer
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The standard method to run code regularly in the `mainloop` is to register a timeout function using the `after` method of the root window.

*But*, whatever you do in such a timeout function (and indeed in all other callbacks), *it should not block*, because that would lock up the mainloop! So you cannot use `input`. But you could read from `sys.stdin`, which is a `io.TextIOWrapper` instance.

You could use `input` in a second thread. But since Tkinter isn't thread-safe, that second thread should *not* use Tkinter functions or methods. So you should not simply update a label from the second thread. You could save/append the input to a global variable, but you'd have to protect that with a lock or mutex. And you'd need to use a timeout function in the main Tkinter thread to test if the lock or mutex is released by the second thread so the Tkinter thread can claim it and access the data. As you can see this is *really* complicated. So mixing Tkinter and threads is generally not recommended.

Comment: It seems very complicated...Could u help me with some type of code as what will be in the second thread and how to trigger main loop continuously

Comment: Because of that complexity I never really use threads with Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to ammend tkinter window and show the text and open picture.I did slight change in the input.py file;and coded as below

```
def vala():
    a=speech()
    if a == "HOME":
        home()
    if a == "NULL":
        timetable()


    window.after(1000,vala)
```

what I have done is I convert it into recursive fn that call itself after 1000ms. In this way, it can be done.
Basically, I have done it with Pocketsphinx as Input (i.e. my project takes speech input and open file/image in tkinter screen and it runs continuously)